# Google+ API leave business review

Tags: google-api, google-plus

With Google requiring users to be logged into their accounts in order to leave a Business Review, is there any legal method around this?  Some customers do not have Google accounts and do not wish to create one, so they are unable to leave comments and reviews.

Is it possible to create a Google+ account, and then use one of their APIs to allow my customers to create a review using the account credentials I pass into the API?  Basically set up a generic Google account, link the credentials in my API calls, and when a user does not have a Google account they can choose to use that method instead which will take their review and post it using the dummy account I set up?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public API for writing reviews. If you want users to write reviews they will have to create and sign-in to their own Google account.

Comment: Google Maps does have some APIs for reading reviews. I don't know how comprehensive they are though.